# Dart, If else statement, is there a better way to select the next Map item?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart and programming in general and I am trying to make my first App!
I have a Floating Action Button at the end of my screen and each time the button gets pressed I would like my variables to change according to the next Map Item provided.
I have used multiple if statements but I do not think that this is the best way to achieve the result.
Also when the last Map item is finally selected I would like to transition to another page. I have written the code, but I do make mistakes with the If statement.

Thank you in advance!

I am sure that I could somehow achieve that using a counter var but I do not know how...
Please help!

import...

```
class DynamicWorkoutStart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DynamicWorkoutStartState createState() => _DynamicWorkoutStartState();
}

class _DynamicWorkoutStartState extends State<DynamicWorkoutStart> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;

  ChewieController _chewieController;

  var ex = {
    'ex1': {
      'title': 'HIGH-KNEE SKIP',
      'videoNr': '1',
      'description1': '- Heel should not touch the ground',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex2': {
      'title': 'OVER-UNDERS',
      'videoNr': '2',
      'description1': '- Flip your Hips!',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex3': {
      'title': 'WALKING HAMSTRING',
      'videoNr': '3',
      'description1': '- Point your Toe upwards the Head.',
      'description2': '- Keep you back flat!'
    },
    'ex4': {
      'title': 'QUAD STRETCH WITH LEAN',
      'videoNr': '4',
      'description1': '- Keep your Abs tight.',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex5': {
      'title': 'FRANKENSTEIN KICKS',
      'videoNr': '5',
      'description1': '- Keep your Knee straight.',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex6': {
      'title': 'ADDUCTOR STRETCH',
      'videoNr': '6',
      'description1': '- Keep your back straight.',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex7': {
      'title': 'HIPFLEXOR STRETCH',
      'videoNr': '7',
      'description1': '- Rotate towrds lead leg.',
      'description2': '- Keep your Hips straight.'
    },
    'ex8': {
      'title': 'HIGH SKIP INTO DEEP SQUAT',
      'videoNr': '8',
      'description1': '- 3 high Skips and then Deep Squat.',
      'description2': '- Get your food over the fence.'
    },
    'ex9': {
      'title': 'QUICKLINE INTO STICK',
      'videoNr': '9',
      'description1': '- Go over the line as fast as you can!',
      'description2': '- 30sec x 3 sets per leg.'
    },
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.asset(
        'assets/videos/${ex['ex1']['videoNr']}.m4v');

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      showControls: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  nextExercise() {
    setState(() {
      if (ex['ex1'] != null) {
        ex['ex1'] = ex['ex2'];
      }

      if (ex['ex2'] != null) {
        ex['ex2'] = ex['ex3'];
      }

      if (ex['ex3'] != null) {
        ex['ex3'] = ex['ex4'];
      }

      if (ex['ex4'] != null) {
        ex['ex4'] = ex['ex5'];
      }

      if (ex['ex5'] != null) {
        ex['ex5'] = ex['ex6'];
      }

      if (ex['ex6'] != null) {
        ex['ex6'] = ex['ex7'];
      }

      if (ex['ex7'] != null) {
        ex['ex7'] = ex['ex8'];
      }

      if (ex['ex8'] != null) {
        ex['ex8'] = ex['ex9'];
      }
      if (ex['ex9'] != null) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FinishDynamicWorkout(),
          ),
        );
      }

      _chewieController.dispose();

      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1 =
            VideoPlayerController.asset(
                'assets/videos/${ex['ex1']['videoNr']}.m4v'),
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        showControls: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ready'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                  child: Text(
                    ex['ex1']['title'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      color: Colors.deepOrange[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Chewie(
                    controller: _chewieController,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    ex['ex1']['description1'],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    ex['ex1']['description2'],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          nextExercise();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
        foregroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[700],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrange your exercises in a list. List is indexed. So in your state introduce `int _currentExercise` variable. Initiate this variable to zero. Then upon button press increment the `_currentExercise` and retrieve the exercise from the list by this index. Something like that. Finish condition would be `if(_currentExercise == _exercises.length -1) Navigator.push....`

Comment: Thank you this really helped! I saw that Maps also have the .length method.

Comment: Try removing screen navigation outside setState()

Comment: Same thing happens. I just get navigated to the next screen as soon as I press the button.

Comment: It's a completely different question and you've already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434390/changing-screen-when-button-pressed-for-the-last-time-at-last-exercise). To avoid any confusion, let's close this question and solve the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dart, you can print a variable in two ways. Let's say you have name = "John". You can either write :
`print(name)` or you can also write `print("$name")`. In the second style, you can also add prefix or suffix to it. Example : `print("My name is $name.")`

So, to reduce the if statements in your code, you can try something like below :

```
int _curr;
int _next ;

for (_curr = 1 ; _curr <= 8 ; _curr++) {
   _next = _curr + 1 ;
   if ( ex['ex$_curr'] != null ) {
    ex['ex$_curr'] = ex['ex$_next'] ;
   }
}
```

Note : This code is not unit tested.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot!

Comment: Would you also be so kind and help me with the last part of my question? When the _curr reaches 9 (last exercice -> 'ex9') how would I be able to transition to another page? Tried this but did not work: if (ex['ex$_curr'] == ex['ex9']) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FinishDynamicWorkout(),
          ),
        );
      }

Comment: Do you get any exception ?

Comment: No nothing, what happens is as soon as i press the button first time i get transitioned to the next screen immediately and not after 8 button presses.

Comment: Remove the screen navigation out of setState()

Comment: Moved the two _curr and _next as well outside setState() for this to work and then also also moved this outside but it does not work:           if (ex['ex$_curr'] == ex['ex9']) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => FinishDynamicWorkout(),
        ),
      );
    }