# Changing Screen when Floating Action Button is pressed for the last time

Tags: flutter, dart

Each time the Floating Action Button is pressed the `nextExercise()` is called. There I managed to update the Ex Map and go the next one. 
Starting from 'ex1' to 'ex2' etc. 
When I reach the 'ex9' (last page) I would like to change a screen because the exercises will have been completed.

I tried a lot of things. Also tried the suggestions from the answers but I can not find the solution, please help!
New Code below:

```
class DynamicWorkoutStart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DynamicWorkoutStartState createState() => _DynamicWorkoutStartState();
}

class _DynamicWorkoutStartState extends State<DynamicWorkoutStart> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;

  ChewieController _chewieController;

  var ex = {
    'ex1': {
      'title': 'HIGH-KNEE SKIP',
      'videoNr': '1',
      'description1': '- Heel should not touch the ground',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex2': {
      'title': 'OVER-UNDERS',
      'videoNr': '2',
      'description1': '- Flip your Hips!',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex3': {
      'title': 'WALKING HAMSTRING',
      'videoNr': '3',
      'description1': '- Point your Toe upwards the Head.',
      'description2': '- Keep you back flat!'
    },
    'ex4': {
      'title': 'QUAD STRETCH WITH LEAN',
      'videoNr': '4',
      'description1': '- Keep your Abs tight.',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex5': {
      'title': 'FRANKENSTEIN KICKS',
      'videoNr': '5',
      'description1': '- Keep your Knee straight.',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex6': {
      'title': 'ADDUCTOR STRETCH',
      'videoNr': '6',
      'description1': '- Keep your back straight.',
      'description2': ''
    },
    'ex7': {
      'title': 'HIPFLEXOR STRETCH',
      'videoNr': '7',
      'description1': '- Rotate towrds lead leg.',
      'description2': '- Keep your Hips straight.'
    },
    'ex8': {
      'title': 'HIGH SKIP INTO DEEP SQUAT',
      'videoNr': '8',
      'description1': '- 3 high Skips and then Deep Squat.',
      'description2': '- Get your food over the fence.'
    },
    'ex9': {
      'title': 'QUICKLINE INTO STICK',
      'videoNr': '9',
      'description1': '- Go over the line as fast as you can!',
      'description2': '- 30sec x 3 sets per leg.'
    },
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.asset(
        'assets/videos/${ex['ex1']['videoNr']}.m4v');

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      showControls: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  nextExercise(BuildContext context) {
int _curr;
int _next;
setState(() {
  for (_curr = 1; _curr <= 8; _curr++) {
    _next = _curr + 1;

    if (ex['ex$_curr'] != null) {
      ex['ex$_curr'] = ex['ex$_next'];
    }
  }

  if (_curr >= 9) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FinishDynamicWorkout(),
      ),
    );
  }

  _chewieController.dispose();

  _chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1 =
        VideoPlayerController.asset(
            'assets/videos/${ex['ex1']['videoNr']}.m4v'),
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    showControls: false,
    autoPlay: true,
    looping: true,
  );
});
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure if we have enough information here to answer your question accurately.  Take a look at our [MCVE] guide, and edit your question to add more detail.  Show us what you tried, why it doesn't work for you, and double check that you have a specific, objective question that can be answered.  I personally would like to see *what* you tried.  Where are you getting an error?  Which line of code isn't doing what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

setState() is used to set the screen state which ultimately updates the widget. You'll have to take out the screen navigation outside setState().

Besides, nextExcercise() doesn't have 'context'. You'll have to pass the context from the Widget build method. Example from [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) page :

```
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Over here, the Navigator.push has the context from the (main) build method.

Comment: This makes totally sense. I did what you told me but the result is the same. As soon as I press the button, once, I get navigated to the last screen. I am guessing that the mistake I make is here: if (ex['ex$_next'] == ex['ex9']) {

Comment: Dear Sukhi, I can not still figure this out, have been trying for many hours. Please be so kind and help me out :)